# Angular 4 how to refresh component

Tags: angular

I have a table that displays data. I also use the jQuery plugin Draggable to drag and drop column as users sees fit. But when I click page 2 the data structure is altered since the columns positions are changed. I was wondering if I can reload the component so the table header can be reloaded.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide your code so that people will be able to help you

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: One thought: Move your column loading to [ngOnInit()](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), and then simply call it again whenever you modify the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I made everything dynamic , The table header in an array and used sortableJs addon to get the changed order, and refresh the array holding the data